# mutt reply-hook: Can't set Cc:

Tags: mutt

My (complete) .muttrc:

```
reply-hook "~t our@group.address" "my_hdr Reply-To: our@group.address"
# Has no effect for unknown reason
reply-hook "~t our@group.address" "my_hdr Cc: Reply-To"
```

The first one works, replies get the Reply-To: header set by default. The second one does not, indepently of the order of the entries. If I change `Cc:` to `MakeSomethingUp:`, it works!

I guess this is something which is fired even after the reply-hooks. But what could it be?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is caused by the default 'metoo' option being 'no'. Add this to your .muttrc:

```
metoo=yes
```